# C code in Linux to C code in Windows

Tags: c, windows, linux, tcp, sockets

I'm having a code written in C that works on Linux. I want this program to work in windows, Are there any differences that I have to make in the code ?

It is a code for Server/Client communication using sockets taken from here :
http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm

Comment: There will be differences. You should try to port your code and ask questions here about specific problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to port the Linux code to Windows. There are differences between Linux and Windows sockets. You can check out [this](http://www.advogato.org/article/672.html) page for further information.

Also, [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y23kc048.aspx) will help you with some of the porting.

Answer (score 2):

You can compile your code under [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) or [MINGW](http://www.mingw.org/), both of which provide a certain degree of Linux-system-call-to-Windows-system-call-mapping, and you may avoid having to rewrite anything at all.

Comment: True! However, sometimes the code has to be prepared in order to compile on Cygwin, and some socket programming statements are unsupported.

Answer (score 1):

Looking briefly at that article that you refer to reveals a few things that will likely need to change (assuming you are going to use something like Visual Studio to build it):

- Replace `read` with `recv`
- Replace `write` with `send`
- Replace `bzero` with `memset`
- Add calls to `WSAStartup` and `WSAShutdown`

Answer (score 0):

Lots!  Mark said it best it seems.  recv and send still work however to a file descriptor.  THe worst part is lack of GNU features like timeval struct without going through horrible windows includes.